# Yo-yo/custard cookies cracking

Tags: baking, cookies, biscuits, australian-cuisine

[image: **enter image description here**]
Any advice on why my yoyo biscuits keep cracking on the surface like this would be much appreciated.
So far I've tried changing the flour (different protein level and using both self raising and plain), butter (different milk fat percentage), custard powder (brand), the temperature, baking time and how much i'm mixing the biscuit dough.

This is the recipe I'm using:

170g butter

60g pure icing sugar

170g Self raising flour

60g custard powder

Suggested baking temperature is 120°C but I've tried from that up to 180°C.
The recipe says to cream the butter and icing sugar, then to mix in the flour and custard powder in small batches. Then roll biscuits into balls and push down with a fork. It then says to bake from 50-60 minutes. I don't think this is happening because the dough in too dry because it's only on the surface and I can rub it off.

Hopefully someone can help me with this :)

Comment: Hi Lily and Welcome! Aren't you supposed to form into balls and press with a fork before baking?

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks :) I rolled each one into 9 gram balls before pressing with a fork to make a domed top flat bottom shape. Although in the photo the fork marks are hidden in the cracking

Comment: I was asking because, in your question, you say the instructions are to bake 50 - 60 minutes and then form the balls and flatten with a fork. That seems backwards.

Comment: For the batch in the photo I used an all purpose flour because originally it ask for a cream of tartar based self raising flour, but I changed to all purpose because I thought the cream of tartar might have been causing the cracking. 

Sorry Cindy, didn't realise I'd written it the wrong way round. I roll then flatten with a fork before baking them.